# A Virtual Local Network Time Protocol?

Tags: java, local, simulation, ntp

We have a simulation project that has several federates communicating through HLA. We have our simulation time `(HH:MM:SS)`, which is different than the real world OS time. We aim to display this simulation time on a lot of NTP wall clocks, each for a federate. Therefore, we need to transmit our simulation time periodically as NTP server packets for these clocks, rather than using either a world-wide NTP server  or the OS time. We cannot find any doc about NTP-Server implementation, although there are lots of NTP-client approaches. Is it possible to generate NTP time packets manually? Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have checked NTP documentation at ntp.org.
http://www.ntp.org/documentation.html

Anyway, maybe be this helps:
http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/onwire.html

Another question. Would you please explain why this is related to java?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Although the link provided may be helpful, you need to include the essential parts of it in your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Also, the latter statement should be a comment, with enough reputation eventually you will be able to comment.

Comment: Of course we have checked the documentation. However, we could not find a solution for our specific problem. Perhaps we did misunderstand the doc by our own fault. Therefore, we have decided to ask here, thinking that an expert may explain with more clear words. İs it wrong? Thanks for the alternative link. Our simulation is developed in Java, so we think that any Java-specific solution may come.

Comment: @Bluex Stacksx Googling and putting copy-paste links cannot be an answer. Also your answer is too basic there is no any experience and useful information for this specific question. That should be detailed.

Comment: @OrhanEROĞLU: even if your simulation is in Java that would be a separate question. Your current question is about installing/setting up a NTP server. You are permitted to update the question to include a related specific Java question, if you have one.

Comment: @doveyg: So, do you have any practical approach about the "main question"?

Comment: @OrhanEROĞLU, Im a programmer not a Sysop. I do happen to know that windows domains come with a NTP server, I presume you can alter the time it uses. How? No idea. Short of finding a package online that would allow you to install a NTP service the only other way I can think of would be to write your own server, or install a windows domain. Good luck.